# How to disable all rows in MUI DataGrid except for row selected for edit

Tags: reactjs, mui-x-data-grid

I would like to be able to disable rows in a MUI DataGrid similar to how Material Table used to do it when an edit button was clicked, as shown in the following image:
[image]

The Material Table is no longer supported by the latest version of React.

I have a MUI DataGrid constructed similar to the [first demo](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/editing/#full-featured-crud) in the edit documentation, in how it uses Edit buttons. I've search in MUI's [DataGrid documentation](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/), as well as StackOverflow, and have looked at the onSelectionModelChange event and edit click handler, but have not found anything helpful to the above goal. Any ideas or insights would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.